# ¿Qué es y para qué me sirve la carpeta Node_modules en mi proyecto?

Tags: jquery, npm

Estoy comenzando y me surge está pregunta. Es importante descargarlo o hay alguna otra forma de desarrollar mi proyecta sin esta carpeta.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

En esa carpeta se van a instalar por defecto todos los los packages que instales con NPM o similares.

No te conviene borrarla si estas trabajando en el proyecto. Ahora si lo que queres es reducir la carga en github o algo asi en realidad podes borrarla, ya que lo que tengas instalado ahi queda configurado en  el archivo package.json. Luego cuando descargues ese proyecto haciendo NPM install podrias recuperar toda la carpeta.

Otra idea es hacer un archivo .**`gitignore`** como indican en [este post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820791/git-ignore-node-modules-folder-everywhere#:%7E:text=gitignore%20%2C%20causing%20the%20node_modules%20folder,and%20you%20can%20safely%20ignore.)

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 2):

node_modules es la carpeta donde se almacenan todas las dependencias y librerías que utilizas en tu proyecto nodejs (Las que importas con `require()`).

Suele ser una carpeta de tamaño grande por lo que no es recomendable subirlo a git, ya que npm tiene el comando `npm install`, el cual lee el archivo package.json e instala las dependencias listadas en él para que el proyecto pueda funcionar.